# Could not resolve JSTL dependency - Tomcat 500 Internal error

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat

I am currently trying to work with JSP/JSTL on Tomcat with Spring MVC. As *.jar dependency I tried the following ones:

- jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.6.jar
- jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.7.jar
- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar

web.xml (first few lines)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
        version="4.0">
```

the jsp file:

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Student Confirmation</title>
</head>
<body>
The student is confirmed: ${student.firstName} ${student.lastName}
<br><br>
Country: ${student.country}
<br><br>
Favorite: ${student.favoriteLanguage}
<br><br>
OS Experiences in:
<c:forEach var="temp" items="${student.osExperiences}">
    ${temp},
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

```java
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Die absolute URI: [http://java.sun.com/jstl/core] kann weder durch web.xml noch durch die JAR-Files dieser Anwendung aufgelöst werden
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:55)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:294)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:81)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:251)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:122)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:431)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:489)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1445)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:144)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:206)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:400)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

And not

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

See:

https://jakarta.ee/specifications/tags/2.0/jakarta-tags-spec-2.0.html#multiple-tag-libraries

If that alone did not not work, also add this dependency (remove the others):

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
<artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```